# Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery Validation Plugin - use class="control-group error"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I've created a form using the Twitter Bootstrap framework and have integrated the jQuery Validation Plugin. I have one form with a series of yes/no questions with radio buttons that I validate to ensure each question is not empty - this is working well.

I would like to leverage the Bootstrap  class="control-group error" to make the error text appear in red so it stands out to the user - currently the "This field is required" text is in black and it's hard to locate.

There's an example of how I would like the error text to appear here:

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

at the end of this section under "Validation states". Here's the specific example that shows a red message after the input field (I only want the error to appear after they have clicked the Submit button):

```
<div class="control-group error">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputError">Input with error</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="inputError">
    <span class="help-inline">Please correct the error</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my form showing one question:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="inputForm">
      <input type="hidden" name="recid" value="1">

      <table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered">

      <h2>Input Form</h2>

          <tr>
          <td>Question 1.</td>
          <td>
              <div class="controls">
                  <label class="radio inline">
          <input type="radio" name="q1" value="Yes" required>Yes          </label>
                  <label class="radio inline">
          <input type="radio" name="q1" value="No" required>No        </label>
                  <label for="q1" class="error"></label>
        </div>
          </td>
          <td>Please answer Yes or No</td>
          </tr>

      </table>
       </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
              <button type="reset" class="btn">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </div>

      </form>
```

I can't work out how to combine the example with my form so that if they submit the form and they haven't answered a question the alert appears in red.

I've setup a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fmdataweb/F28PF/) that shows this is action if that helps.

Comment: This is a question about jQuery Validate... so show your jQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: BTW, `class="control-group error"` actually contains _two_ classes, `.control-group` and `.error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `errorClass` option to set the jQuery Validate plugin to your desired `class` for errors.  This will apply both `.control-group` and `.error` classes upon a validation error...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     // initialize the plugin
     $("#inputForm").validate({ 
         errorClass: "control-group error"
     });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F28PF/1/

See documentation for the plugin options:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

---

**EDIT**:

As pointed out, the default behavior puts the `errorClass` on the message and the `input` element.

If you need to toggle the error/valid classes on something else, you would leverage the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // initialize the plugin
    $("#inputForm").validate({
        errorClass: "control-group error",
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest(".control-group").addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest(".control-group").addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't this add .control-group and .error to the input tag? This is a not a very bootstrap-friendly way to do this. Why not add the error to the control-group that wraps the input instead?

Comment: @Ryan, yes it adds the class to the `input` element as that's the default plugin behavior.  To toggle classes on another element would require the usage of `highlight` and `unhighlight` as described in my edits.

Answer (score -1):

To use the control-group the way bootstrap was intended to be used, you want to set the value of the surrounding control-group. The accepted answer isn't quite right, you don't want to put control-group on the input itself, but the container. This code should work.

```
$("#page-form").validate({
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest(".control-group").addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest(".control-group").addClass(validClass).removeClass(errorClass);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Perfect, this is adds the class to the already existing `.control-group`.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. If you're using bootstrap the way they intend for it to be used, this is the preferable method. It will make sure that the label and field are colored via the class.